# How to switch the order of limit and integration here?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\phi_\varepsilon(x):=\varepsilon^{-n}e^{-\pi|\varepsilon^{-1}x|^2}$. It is straightforward to see that $\phi_\varepsilon(x)$ is an approximate identity.

I want to prove that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert dx= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert dx .$$

**Can we apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem here? If not, could we find another way out, namely how to switch the order of limit and integration of**

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert dx?$$

If we apply **Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem**, then we need to do two things:

1. Prove that $\phi_\varepsilon*f(x)-f(x)$ converges pointwise to a function $h(x)$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$.
2. Prove that $\phi_\varepsilon*f(x)-f(x)$ is dominated by some integrable function $g(x)$ in the sense that
   $$|\phi_\varepsilon*f(x)-f(x)|\le |g(x)|.$$

But I’m totally stuck here. Could you give me some help? Thank you!

***Motivation:***

I’m reading the proof of Fourier Inversion theorem:

> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}d\xi=f(x)$$
>   almost everywhere, where $f,\widehat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I managed to understand the proof (including the equality right below) until
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}e^{-\pi|\varepsilon \xi|^2}d\xi= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\phi_\varepsilon*f(x).$$

It is mentioned in many books but there are always no more details. We are always told to apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem here and then the proof shall be concluded.

I managed to understand that the left side is equal to 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}d\xi.$$ For the left side, the theorem is indeed applied.

**For the right side**, **if the equality that I stated on the top holds**, then since
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\Vert f*\phi_\varepsilon-f\Vert_1=0,$$we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert dx=0.$$
There is a [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644943/f-has-a-zero-integral-on-every-measurable-set-prove-f-is-zero-almost-everyw) stating that

> $E$ is a measurable set and $f$ is integrable on $E$. Then $$\int_E |f|~dm=0$$if and only if $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Therefore we have $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\phi_\varepsilon*f=f$ almost everywhere. It completes the proof.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To conclude the Fourier Inversion Theorem using the equality $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}e^{-\pi|\varepsilon \xi|^2}\,\mathrm{d}\xi= \phi_\varepsilon*f(x),$$ it suffices to have $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}f*\phi_{\varepsilon}(x)=f(x)\qquad\text{for Lebesgue-a.e. } x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$ I wonder what is your motivation for considering a seemingly much stronger statement $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert \, \mathrm{d}x= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\vert\phi_\varepsilon*f-f\right\vert \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: I am not sure if this is the most economic solution, but I would first write $$f*\phi_{\varepsilon}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{1}{|B_{\varepsilon s}(0)|} \int_{B_{\varepsilon s}(0)} f(x+y)  \, \mathrm{d}y \biggr) 2\pi |B_1(0)| s^{n+1} e^{-\pi s^2} \, \mathrm{d}s$$ and then apply the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem together with the Dominated Convergence Theorem. I suspect that the use of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem is unavoidable since the corresponding a.e.-convergence in the case of the indicator function $\phi=\frac{1}{|B_1|}\mathbf{1}_{B_1}$ is exactly that theorem.

Comment: Approximation-to-the-identity statements may take various forms, and in particular, may involve different modes of convergence. $L^1$-convergence (like what you mentioned in the comment) is easier to establish using $L^1$-continuity, but one cannot directly deduce a.e.-convergence out of this as the latter is generally much harder. Some textbooks (such as Wheeden and Zygmund, *Measure and Integral*) has an exposition on various versions of approximation-to-the-identity statements, including those for a.e.-pointwise convergence.

Comment: Here, $B_r(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|y-x\|<r\}$ is the $n$-ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. So $B_1=B_1(0)$ is the unit ball at the origin and $B_{\varepsilon s}(0)$ is the ball of radius $\varepsilon s$ at the origin. I also utilized the indicator function notation: $$\mathbf{1}_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A, \\ 0, & x \notin A \end{cases} $$ This function is sometimes called as the characteristic function and denoted by $\chi_A$. I will try to write down a more detailed answer when time permits.

Comment: Bounding that average near $\varepsilon=0$ follows from that limit statement, and this statement holds only if $f$ is locally integrable. In order to bound this average when $\varepsilon$ is far from the origin, you need the integrability of $f$ over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In such case, it is easy to check that $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to\infty} \frac{1}{|B_{\varepsilon s}|}\int_{B_{\varepsilon s}(x)}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0$$ using the trivial bound $$\left|\int_{B_{\varepsilon s}(x)}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(z)|\,\mathrm{d}z=\|f\|_{L^1}.$$

Comment: If $f$ is integrable and $x$ is chosen to satisfy $\text{(*)}$, then the function $$g(r)=\frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r(x)}f(y)\mathrm{d}y$$ is continuous and has both limits $$\lim_{r\to0^+}g(r)=f(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{r\to\infty}g(r)=0.$$ This guarantees that $g$ is bounded. So it is possible to choose a positive number $A$ that satisfies $|g(r)|\leq A$ for all $r > 0$. Of course, the smallest possible choice would be $$A=\sup_{r>0}g(r). $$ In fact, this quantity arises in the proof of Lebesgue Diff. Theorem and is called the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B_r$ denote the ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Then Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem tells:

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ be a locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
>   $$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{|B_r|} \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = f(x) \tag{*}$$
>   holds for Lebesgue-a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function which is either non-negative or integrable, and let $\phi_{\varepsilon}$ be as in OP. Then

\begin{align*}
(f \ast \phi_{\varepsilon})(x)
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x-y)\varepsilon^{-n}e^{-\pi|y/\varepsilon|^2} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x-y) \biggl( \int_{|y|}^{\infty} 2\pi r \varepsilon^{-n-2}e^{-\pi r^2 / \varepsilon^2} \, \mathrm{d}r \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \biggl( \int_{\{|y| < r\}} f(x-y)  \, \mathrm{d}y \biggr) 2\pi r \varepsilon^{-n-2}e^{-\pi r^2 / \varepsilon^2} \, \mathrm{d}r \tag{$\because$ Fubini} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{1}{|B_{\varepsilon s}|} \int_{B_{\varepsilon s}(x)} f(z)  \, \mathrm{d}z \biggr) 2\pi |B_1| s^{n+1} e^{-\pi s^2} \, \mathrm{d}s,
\end{align*}

where the substitutions $r=\varepsilon s$ and $z=x-y$ are utilized in the final step. Write

$$k(s) := 2\pi |B_1| s^{n+1} e^{-\pi s^2}$$

for simplicity. Then either by a direct computation or by plugging $f \equiv 1$ to the identity above, we note that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} k(s) \, \mathrm{d}s = 1.$$

Now assume that $f$ is integrable. Then for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $\text{(*)}$, the map

$$ (0, \infty) \ni r \mapsto \frac{1}{|B_{r}|} \int_{B_{r}(x)} f(z)  \, \mathrm{d}z $$

is bounded and converges to $f(x)$ as $r \to 0$. So by the dominated convergence theorem,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} (f \ast \phi_{\varepsilon})(x)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \biggl( \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{|B_{\varepsilon s}|} \int_{B_{\varepsilon s}(x)} f(z)  \, \mathrm{d}z \biggr) k(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)k(s) \, \mathrm{d}s
= f(x)
\end{align*}

as required.

Comment: @Benny, The identity we derived holds for any measurable function $f$ which is either non-negative or integrable. So if we plug $f\equiv1$, then $$1=(f*\phi_{\varepsilon})(0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\frac{1}{|B_{\varepsilon s}|}\int_{B_{\varepsilon s}}f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\biggr)k(s)\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_{0}^{\infty}k(s)\,\mathrm{d}s.$$ If you want to see this directly, note that$$\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{n+1}e^{-\pi s^2}\,\mathrm{d}s\stackrel{(u=\pi s^2)}=\frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{n/2}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{2\pi^{n/2+1}}$$ by the definition of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Benny, Glad it helped :)

Comment: @Benny, Note that the function is shifted:$$\frac{1}{|B_r|} \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{|B_r|} \int_{B_r} f(x+y) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

Comment: @Benny, Indeed I exploited the symmetry $\phi_{\varepsilon}(-x)=\phi_{\varepsilon}(x)$ to flip that sign to make the expression look better, but this is not a necessity. Let me try to make a quick fix to remove some of the tricks involved.

Comment: @Benny, You are correct. And of course that bound $A$ follows from $(*)$. Glad that you figured this out. :)

Comment: @Benny, The Jacobian of the substitution $z=\Phi(y):=x-y$ is $\operatorname{Jac}(\Phi)=\det(D\Phi)=(-1)^n$, and so, $$\mathrm{d}z=\left|\operatorname{Jac}(\Phi)\right|\,\mathrm{d}y=\mathrm{d}y.$$ Integrals over sets and over oriented manifolds (such as the "oriented interval" $[b,a]$ where $b>a$) should be distinguished, and how differential forms transform is also  affected by this.

Comment: @Benny, The reference that I mentioned before contains a proof of the theorem that $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} f*\phi_{\varepsilon}(x) = f(x)$$for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ if $f$ is integrable, $|\phi(x)|\leq\frac{C}{(1+|x|)^{n+\lambda}}$ for some $C, \lambda>0$, and $\int\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have that it is enough to show $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} f*\phi_{\epsilon}(x) = f$ a.e., I would just like to show a solution that doesn't require Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem. First, the integral of $\phi_{\epsilon}$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to 1 since
\begin{align*}
     \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi_{\epsilon}(x) \ dx &= \epsilon^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\pi\epsilon^{-2} |x|^2}\ dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\pi|y|^2}dy\\
&= 1,
\end{align*}
where we employed the change of variable 
$$\epsilon y = x \implies \epsilon^n dy = dx,$$
and I also had to look at the wiki for the [integral of an n-dimensional Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization).

**EDIT:** What is written below is *not* sufficient to prove this this theorem.

Now,

\begin{align*}
     \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left| f*\phi_{\epsilon}(x) - f(x)\right| &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x-y)\phi_{\epsilon}(y) \ dy - f(x)\right|\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x-y)\phi_{\epsilon}(y) \ dy - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\phi_{\epsilon}(y) \ dy\right|\\
&\leq \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\phi_{\epsilon}(y)|| f(x-y)- f(x)|\ dy.
\end{align*}
 <strike>Now, $\phi$ is clearly bounded and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so we can apply dominated convergence to pass the limit through the integral to get the desired result.</strike>

Comment: I am not sure if $\{ |\phi_{\varepsilon}(y)||f(x-y)-f(x)|\}_{\varepsilon > 0}$ is dominated. The envelope of the family $\{|\phi_{\varepsilon}(y)|\}_{\varepsilon>0}$ will be roughly proportional to $|x|^{-n}$, which is not integrable.

Comment: I believe you're correct!. I think this can be fixed by employing the change of variable again, using $\epsilon z = y$, to get
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\phi_{\epsilon}(y)|| f(x-y)- f(x)|\ dy = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |e^{-\pi|z|^2}| f(x-\epsilon z)- f(x)|\ dz. 
$$
The first term should now be dominated.

Comment: But how to prove $e^{-\pi|z|^2}| f(x-\epsilon z)- f(x)|$ is integrable? Do you mind adding more details?

Comment: Consider the case $n=1$. Then there exists a non-negative integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ which is unbounded on any open interval. Then for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the following holds:$$\forall z \neq 0\:\qquad\limsup_{\varepsilon\to0^+}e^{-\pi z^2}\left|f(x-\varepsilon z)-f(x)\right|=+\infty$$ So the family $\{e^{-\pi z^2}\left|f(x-\varepsilon z)-f(x)\right|\}_{\varepsilon>0}$ cannot be dominated by an integrable function for every $x$.

Comment: My mistake! I assumed this proof would be similar to [approximation by mollifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Properties), but in this case we are not convoluting $f$ with a function that has compact support so the proof appears to follow differently.