#  has a zero integral on every measurable set. Prove  is zero almost everywhere.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I wanted to complete the proof given here,
[$f$ has a zero integral on every measurable set. Prove $f$ is zero almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644943/f-has-a-zero-integral-on-every-measurable-set-prove-f-is-zero-almost-everyw).

Let, $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be our measure space. Let $f$ be integrable. Assume that $\int_A f d\mu = 0$ for every set $A \in \Sigma$. Prove that $f = 0$ a.e. [$\mu$] on $X$.

Let, $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let, $E_{r} = \{x \in X: f(x) \ge r \}$. Then,
$$\int_{E_r} r ~ d\mu \le \int_{E_r}f ~ d\mu \le 0 \implies \int_{E_r}r ~d\mu =0 \implies \mu(E_r) = 0.$$

Let, $\{q_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a decreasing sequence of rationals that converge to $0$. We have that,
$$\bigcup_{n \ge 1}E_{q_n}  = \{x \in X: f(x) > 0 \}.$$
Since $E_{q_n}$ is a increasing sequence of sets because $\{q_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is the decreasing sequence of rationals that converge to $0$. We can obtain,
$$\mu( \bigcup_{n \ge 1}E_{q_n}  )  = \mu(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_{q_n} )  = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_{q_n} ) = 0.$$
Hence, $\mu(\{x \in X: f(x) > 0 \} ) = 0$. Let, $r' \in \mathbb{Q} $ such that $r' < 0$.  Let, $E'_{r'} = \{x \in X: f(x) \le r' < 0 \}$.
We have that,
$$\int_{E_r'}f(x) ~ d\mu \le \int_{E_r'}r' ~d\mu \implies \int_{E_r}f(x)~d\mu \le \int_{E_r'}r' \implies 0 \le \int_{E_r'}r' \implies 0 \le - \int_{E_r'}|r'|. $$
So,
$$ 0 \le - \int_{E_r'}|r'| \implies \int_{E_r'}|r'| \le 0 \implies \mu(E_{r'}') = 0. $$

Let, $\{q_n'\}_{n\ge1}$ be an increasing sequence of rationals that converge to $0$. Then,
$$\bigcup_{n \ge 1}\mu(E'_{q_n'})  = \{x \in X: f(x) < 0 \}.$$
Using a similar argument as before we can obtain that, $\mu(\{x \in X: f(x) < 0 \}) = 0$. Hence, $f =0$ a.e. on $X$ w.r.t. $\mu$.

Does my proof look good? Thanks.